# Databricks Repo with Azure DevOps - 400 Bad Request when trying to add repo

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, databricks

when trying to use the databricks Repo feature with AzureDevOps, I am not able to add a repo to my databricks workspace [add repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42hPn.png) and I am getting a Bad Request as Response [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h5gd.png).
Under User settings -> Git Integration -> Git Provider I have selected Azure Devops Services and in advanced settings Notebook Git Versioning is enabled.

I tried with a different browser, aswell as in private mode. In addition I tried to delete my cookies, but still got the same error. The integration to GitHub with a PAT works fine. I am also able to sync notebooks to the Azure DevOps repository, but the repo feature itself is not working.

I work in a corporate environment and we use single sign on with Azure Active Directory to authenticate to the Workspace. I really dont have an idea what causes the issue.
My only guess is that something AD authentification related is not set properly.
**Sometimes** when trying to access the workspace via the azure portal I receive the message that my account has no Contributer or Owner Role on the workspace [role warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjjOE.png), which is strange since I am an admin in the Databricks workspace. After clicking on sign in with AzureAD I receive the warning: AADSTS90015: Requested query string is too long [query string warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYJ5f.png). However if I click back in the browser and click again on sign in with AzureID I am able to access the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

The 400 Bad Request is an error from Azure DevOps. We would recommend you reach out to Azure DevOps support for help on this.

Regarding the role warning, this is related to your permissions on the workspace object in Azure Active Directory (rather than your admin permissions in the workspace) - the error message indicates that when we looked up your permissions in Azure, they didn't match those of either a contributor or owner on the workspace. However, if you are a contributor and see this error occasionally, that is unexpected behavior and we can surface this internally.

Comment: Hi @user13015326,

I don't think the issue occurs on Azure DevOps services.
Normally, All HTTP response status codes that are in the 4xx category are considered `client error responses` rather than `server error responses`.
Generally the **400 Bad Request Error** is caused by that the client sends a request with invalid syntax. The server was unable to process the request.
Azure DevOps services has provided the available and valid interfaces (API and CLI), if you call the interfaces with incorrect syntax on the client, you may get the 400 Error.

Comment: @user13015326 The error meesage regarding the contributor rights is definetively not always present and I am not able to say when it shows up and when not. Colleagues of mine with the same permissions an the AAD on the Databricks resource do not experience such error messages.

Comment: @Bright Ran-MSFT I agree with you. I think that my querystring that is send to the AzureDevOps API is malformed (maybe too long?) and therefore I receive a 400 response. I tried to clear all my cookies and with a different browser, but no success either.

Comment: What I mean by it being an Azure DevOps error is that the 400 comes from Azure DevOps when we present the user credentials to try to connect, possibly when a user’s credentials are invalid or something of this sort, rather than the 400 being thrown by Databricks. It’s unlikely to be related to the long query string error you’re seeing as that error is related to the login flow, which is separate from the repos flow. If you send an email to reposfeedback@databricks.com with your workspace ID, username, and Azure Databricks region we can take a closer look for you.

Comment: @user13015326 Ok I got it. I will reach out to reposfeedback@databricks.com. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your account that signed in Databricks has the correct permissions in the workspace on Azure Portal, and on Azure DevOps to access the Git repository.

You also can try to use the same account to sign in Azure DevOps to see if you can access the specified repository.

For more details, you can see "[Azure Databricks - Repos for Git integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos)".

Comment: I can acces the Azure DevOps Repo via the browser. I double checked the permissions on DevOps and I am in the same groups as my colleague, who is able to link to an Azure Databricks repo. So I dont think it is a permission issue in Azure DevOps.